# Android application not full-screening

Tags: android, actionscript-3, fullscreen

I'm starting an app in AS3 (yeah, yeah, dying language and all, I know) but for some reason it's not full-screening despite having the XML set to do so. When I debug the app (a simple test with two buttons each taking up 50% of the screen) in the SWF viewer or whatever, I get this (which is what I want): [image]

When I run it on the emulator, however, I get this:

[image]

How can I remove that bar?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can in AS3.  You could try using the flash fullscreen mode.

Answer (score -1):

According to the Android documentation, you can do this for Android 4.0 or high by using the following code:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

(Original documentation found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html).)

Comment: This question isn't Java related